# Criptografar dentro da procedure

Tags: sql-server, criptografia, stored-procedures

Olá! Estou fazendo uma procedure para inserção dos dados do usuário e gostaria de saber como faz para criptografar o campo de senha dentro da procedure.
Minha tabela:

```
create procedure cadUsuario(
@nome varchar(100),
@email varchar(150),
@data date,
@cpf int, 
@rg int,
@senha varchar(100))
as begin 
    
    insert into 
    tb_usuario(nm_usuario, nm_email, dt_nasc, cd_cpf, cd_rg, nm_senha) 
    values (@nome, @email, @data, @cpf, @rg, @senha)
end
go
```

Comment: Normalmente a criptografia é feita fora do ambiente do SQL. O banco de dados já recebe os dados encriptados e o servidor faz a cifra. Fazendo a cifra dentro do SQL você estará vulnerável à inserção de informação corrompida, invasão de cifra, descriptografia, etc.

Comment: então, na hora da que eu der um get no que o usuário entrou, eu vou precisar criptografar e depois inserir esse valor no banco?

Comment: Basicamente sim, e de mesma forma você deverá descriptografar quando obter os dados do banco. Tome cuidado com SQL Injection na hora de fazer as queries.

Comment: tá bom! obrigada!